# PHPUnit - Testing for cases that are not handled by the base function

Tags: php, phpunit

I have a query about PHPUnit. How do I create a test case in PHPUnit for cases that are NOT handled in the base class itself. For example, Please Consider the following showMessage method.

```
Class Message
{

    public function showMessage($type = 1)
    {

        if(1 == $type){
            return 'Success';
        }elseif(2 == $type){
            return 'ERROR';
        }

    }

}
```

In the showMessage method above, there should also be a case that if the `$type` is anything other than 1 or 2, so it should have a else case, so the conditions should be something like

```
    if(1 == $type){
        return 'Success';
    }elseif(2 == $type){
        return 'ERROR';
    }else{
        return 'UNKNOWN';
    }
```

Thanks for any inputs

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you are asking but I'll give it a shot..

To test the `showMessage` method in your first code block you would do something like this as functions will return `null` when either no `return` is specified or just a `return;` is.

```
public function testShowMessage()
{
    $msg = new Message();

    $this->assertEquals('Success', $msg->showMessage(1));
    $this->assertEquals('ERROR', $msg->showMessage(2));
    $this->assertEquals(null, $msg->showMessage(-1));
    $this->assertEquals(null, $msg->showMessage(3));
    $this->assertEquals(null, $msg->showMessage('test'));
}
```

The test case for your second method would be:

```
public function testShowMessage()
{
    $msg = new Message();

    $this->assertEquals('Success', $msg->showMessage(1));
    $this->assertEquals('ERROR', $msg->showMessage(2));
    $this->assertEquals('UNKNOWN', $msg->showMessage(-1));
    $this->assertEquals('UNKNOWN', $msg->showMessage(3));
    $this->assertEquals('UNKNOWN', $msg->showMessage('test'));
}
```

The way the `showMessage` method is wrote in my opinion should throw an exception if it is not passed a `0` or a `1` as it enforces better design, instead of just trying to pass any old value to the method. I would refactor this method to something such as this:

```
/**
 * @param int $type
 * @return string
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function showMessage($type)
{
    // Will be cast to 0 if it cannot be converted. 0 is not used in this method.
    switch ((int) $type) {
        case 1:
            return 'Success';
        case 2:
            return 'ERROR';
        default:
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("\$type requires an integer value of 1 or 2.");
    }

}
```

Although I wouldn't of designed this sort of method in the first place, it is making the best of this situation. Here are the relevant test cases:

```
public function testShowMessage()
{
    $msg = new Message();

    $this->assertEquals('Success', $msg->showMessage(1));
    $this->assertEquals('ERROR', $msg->showMessage(2));
}

/**
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testShowMessageExceptionWithInteger()
{
    $msg = new Message();
    $msg->showMessage(0);
}

/**
 * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
 */
public function testShowMessageExceptionWithString()
{
    $msg = new Message();
    $msg->showMessage("test");
}
```

In your original method you specify `$type` as an optional parameter, it seems that you are adding all this avoidance code to distance yourself away from any method/data that is calls/passed to the `showMessage()` method. Another example of this is returning `UNKNOWN`. There should be checks before this or an exception so it can be caught easily whilst testing. This could introduce bugs at a later date.

Hope that clears things up.

Comment: The only thing I would add, is use a constant instead of 1/2, so that in the calling code you have an explanation of what you are calling, and the numbers can change in the future without needing to refactor.  showMessage(Message::SUCCESS); which would have the constants defined.  Potentially, Message::SUCCESS might be something else, such as prompts for a Message Box (showMessage(Message::OK_BUTTON_ONLY);

Comment: @StevenScott I agree, I did think about that whilst writing it but I didn't want to deviate too much.

Comment: @FruityP Thanks for your reply. I am sorry if my question was confusing. Let me tell you why exactly I asked the question. I need to write test cases for codes that one of my fellow mate wrote and I noticed that he didn't covered the `else{ return 'UNKNOWN';}` part in his code. So I wanted to know how do I write a test case that would fail his code by passing a value in his `showMessage()` method that was not handled by him in his code. I hope I am clear now :) Thanks

Comment: If he does not have the `UNKNOWN` else condition that this line should do the trick.

`$this->assertEquals('UNKNOWN', $msg->showMessage(-1));` You can also use `$this->fail()` if it returns `null`.

Comment: right, but how would my test tell him that he has missed adding a condition unless PHPUnit returns a "Failure" count i.e. Failures: 1. I am thinking this as a part of negative testing where my test cases fails whereever the developer has missed adding a condition or a case in their code.

Comment: Yeah, if he has not accounted for `UNKNOWN` then that will fail as it will return `null` and not `UNKNOWN` if he has no `else` clause.

You can alternatively perform a conditional check and use `$this->fail()` also.

This will fail the test and alert him to it.